# How to calculate volume profile between the start and end time?

Tags: pine-script

I use price and time inputs specified by the user:

```
startPrice = input.price(0, inline="StartPoint", confirm=true)
startTime = input.time(0, inline="StartPoint", confirm=true)

endPrice = input.price(0, inline="EndPoint", confirm=true)
endTime = input.time(0, inline="EndPoint", confirm=true)
```

and I want to calculate the volume profile like the build indicator does. But I can't find a way of doing it. I can calculate the volume profile by any fixed period or using lookback bars count, but how to calculate it using arbitrary start and end times?

Comment: It's not possible yet using native Pinescript.